# Load relations only when a field in parent table is true

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have a parent table named `Post` which has a boolean column named `is_anonymous`. The `Post` table has a relation to `Users` table. I want to load this relation only when `is_anonymous` set to `false`. Is there a way I can achieve this?

The below relation gives users for all the posts.

```
$institute = Institute::where('inst_id', '=', $institute_id)->with(
        ['posts' => function ($posts) {
            $posts->with(['user', 'tags']);
        }]
    )->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->skip($skip)->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using lazy loading. I think there is no other way I can do this. Please add answers if you find a better way.

```
$posts = Institute::where('inst_id', '=', $institute_id)->first()->posts()->with('tags')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->skip($skip)->take(10)->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if (!$post['is_anonymous']) {
        $post->load('user');
    }
}
```

Or,

To be performance friendly, I'm currently solving this using the below query and removing the key user, as iterating over a list of 10 items and removing is always better than making 10 queries (worst case)

```
$posts = Institute::where('inst_id', '=', $institute_id)->first()->posts()->with(['user', 'tags'])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->skip($skip)->take(10)->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if ($post['is_anonymous']) {
       unset($post['user'])
    }
}
```